A RenderFlex overflowed by 837 pixels on the bottom
I am trying to build a 'Cat or Dog Classifier App' using Android Studio. When I run the app, there are options for capturing image through the camera and selecting image from the gallery. But when I capture or select an image, the result is not shown. An error shows saying "A RenderFlex overflowed by 837 pixels on the bottom." How to solve this issue?
It is the code of splashscreen.dart file:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_native_splash/flutter_native_splash.dart';
import 'package:untitled/home.dart';

class MySplash extends StatefulWidget {
  const MySplash({super.key});

  @override
  State<MySplash> createState() => _MySplashState();
}

class _MySplashState extends State<MySplash> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2), () {
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Home()));
    });
    FlutterNativeSplash.remove();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.blueAccent,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Image.asset('assets/cat_and_dog.png'),
                const SizedBox(height: 20),
                const Text(
                  'Cat & Dog Classifier',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 25,
                      color: Colors.yellowAccent),
                ),
              ],
          ),
    );
  }
}

And it is the code of home.dart file:
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:tflite/tflite.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({super.key});

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  bool _loading = true;
  late File _image;
  late List _output;
  final picker = ImagePicker();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadMode1().then((value) {
      setState(() {

      });
    });
  }

  detectImage(File image) async {
    var output = await Tflite.runModelOnImage(path: image.path,
        numResults: 2,
        threshold: 0.6,
        imageMean: 127.5,
        imageStd: 127.5);
    setState(() {
      _output = output!;
      _loading = false;
    });
  }

  loadMode1() async {
    await Tflite.loadModel(model: 'assets/model_unquant.tflite', labels: 'assets/labels.txt');
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    super.dispose();
  }

  pickImage() async {
    final pickedFile = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    if (pickedFile!= null) {
      setState(() {
        _image = File(pickedFile.path);
      });
      detectImage(_image);
    }
  }

  pickGalleryImage() async {
    final pickedFile = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    if (pickedFile!= null) {
      setState(() {
        _image = File(pickedFile.path);
      });
      detectImage(_image);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24),
          child: Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget> [
              SizedBox(height: 50),
              Text('Machine Learning Applied',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 20),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 5),
              Text('Cat vs Dog Detector App',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    fontSize: 30),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 50),
              Center(child: _loading?
              Container(
                width: 350,
                child: Column(children: <Widget> [
                  Image.asset('assets/cat_and_dog.png'),
                  SizedBox(height: 50),
                ],),
              ) : Container(
                child: Column(children: <Widget> [
                  Container(
                    height: 250,
                    child: Image.file(_image),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 20),
                  _output!= null? Text ('${_output[0]['label']}',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 15),) : Container(),
                  SizedBox(height: 10),
                ],),
              ),
              ),
              Container(width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: Column(children: <Widget> [
                  GestureDetector(onTap: (){
                    pickImage();
                  },
                    child: Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 250,
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 18),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.redAccent,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                      ),
                      child: Text(
                        'Capture an image',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 5),
                  GestureDetector(onTap: (){
                    pickGalleryImage();
                  },
                    child: Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 250,
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 18),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.redAccent,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                      ),
                      child: Text(
                        'Select an image',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Does this answer your question? Flutter (Dart): Exceptions caused by rendering / A RenderFlex overflowed
